# IFrame Fangate App & Redirecting

Tags: javascript, facebook

I know that it may simply not be possible due to cross-domain javascript security, but I'm trying to find a way to redirect a user to our wall after they like our page on the fangate app. The fangate app is working fine, and I was using the code below when someone has liked the page.

top.location.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/investools?sk=wall';

This works in FF/Chrome, but not in IE. Anybody have any ideas on what I may be missing? Will the app have to authenticate to allow this type of functionality? Would there be a way to possibly due this using the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Because IE doesn't execute the script tag, You have to attach an event handler to `<body>` tag of the iFrame